# libsndfile truncates path at 512 characters when using sf_open

Tags: c++, libsndfile

The title says it all. When writing to a file with a long path, the path is truncated.

```
string filename="/pathwithmorethan512characters/song.wav";  
sf_open(filename.c_str(), SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo);
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

I'm using linux with libsndfile.so.1.0.25.

Comment: Actually, in src/common.h the macro SF_FILENAME_LEN is set to 512. But why?

Comment: I suggest you raise a ticket on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Since October 2014 on revision [1.0.26](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/compare/1.0.26...master#diff-06b1446c4b9f9f1cf62986e0b1f7ca66), the `common.h` file has been updated and storage space has been doubled.

You can now store paths up to 1024 characters:

```
#define SF_FILENAME_LEN         (1024)
```

The corresponding error message has been updated too. This example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sndfile.h"

int main(void)
{
  char *inFileName;
  SNDFILE *inFile;
  SF_INFO inFileInfo;

  inFileName = "long_file_name_above_1024_characters.wav";
  inFile = sf_open(inFileName, SFM_READ, &inFileInfo);
  puts(sf_strerror(inFile));

  sf_close(inFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Returns:

> Error : Supplied filename too long.